# Как создать https подключение в python socket?

Tags: python, сокет, ssl, https

Я создаю сервер на socket python и мне бы хотелось иметь https подключение. Я долго искал ответ в интернете, но то что мне нужно так и не нашёл. Помогите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать (вообще не разбираюсь в этой теме, но на python программирую не плохо)

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("", 443))
s.listen(10)
run = True
while run:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.send(b"hello")
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вам нужно что-то типа `fastapi` https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/

Comment: А можно пожалуйста по подробнее? Просто я не разбираюсь в ssl

Comment: Вы можете в двух словах описать функционал Вашей программы. Ну буквально Что? Откуда? В Каком виде? Куда? Зачем?

Comment: import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("", 443))
s.listen(10)


run = True

while run:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    conn.send(b"hello")
    conn.close()

Как сделать чтобы при подключении в сайте на https://127.0.0.1/ заходилось на сервер? Мне нужен сам этот https протокол

Comment: Я немного не это имел ввиду, как выглядит примитивный сокет на 443-м порту я в курсе. Что должна делать программа, которую Вы создаете, для которой Вы создаете этот сокет?

Comment: Писать свой собственный http(s) сервер — в 99% случаев крайне хреновая идея. Если возможно, лучше взять какой-то готовый и проверенный временем сервер/фреймворк, к примеру fastapi уже упомянули выше

Comment: А вообще на уровне питона обычно в принципе не делают никакой ssl, а отдают работу с ним какому-нибудь впереди стоящему веб-серверу вроде nginx — это проще, гибче и безопаснее

Comment: Тут пример и сервера и клиента и инструкции, как создать сертификат  https://github.com/romank0/python-tls